# Problem that values are not reflected in Jqgrid when .jqGrid('setCell', i, 'columnName', '') is executed in IE

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am currently trying to update values in Jqgrid using .jqGrid('setCell', i, 'columnName', Value).

If the value of Value is not '', the value is reflected in the table when .jqGrid('setCell', i, 'columnName', Value) is executed, but if the value of Value is '', it is not updated and displayed as the previous value.

Furthermore, this happens only in IE, but in chrome, the value is normally updated. So, does anyone know how to make the table display a blank field when the value is ''?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The text below is from the documentation of Guriddo jqGrid.

```
setCell(string rowid, string colname, [string data], [mixed class] ,[object properties],[boolean forceup])
Change the content of particular cell and can set class or style properties.

parameters

    string rowid - the is of the grid row
    string colname - column name as defined in colModel or index staring from 0
    string data - the new data that will be set. If empty string the content will not be changed
    mixed class - if the class is a string we set it as class. If the class is object we set the properties with the css jQuery method
    object properties - attribute properties to be set
    boolean forceup - if the parameter is set to true we perform update of the cell instead that the data parameter is empty.

return
jqGrid object
```

Using the last parameter to true will help you to achive what you want - this is in case you use Guriddo jqGrid.

Comment: So there was another argument to setcell. That was a blind spot.
I have just confirmed that it works correctly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help..